# Unexpected result of NATURAL JOIN and USING Clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I am learning about obtaining data from multiple tables and I have a question regarding NATURAL JOIN and the USING clause. So I have 2 tables that I'm extracting data from; employees and departments.

```
SQL> describe employees 
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 EMPLOYEE_ID                                        NUMBER(6)
 FIRST_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(20)
 LAST_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 EMAIL                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 PHONE_NUMBER                                       VARCHAR2(20)
 HIRE_DATE                                 NOT NULL DATE
 JOB_ID                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(8,2)
 COMMISSION_PCT                                     NUMBER(2,2)
 MANAGER_ID                                         NUMBER(6)
 DEPARTMENT_ID                                      NUMBER(4)

SQL> describe departments
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 DEPARTMENT_ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 DEPARTMENT_NAME                                    VARCHAR2(30)
 MANAGER_ID                                         NUMBER(6)
 LOCATION_ID                                        NUMBER(4)
```

When I use NATURAL JOIN and USING in two different expressions, I have two different outputs. I know that USING matches specifically one column in both tables, but how does this affect the output? How come the expression with USING produces one extra value compared to the NATURAL JOIN?

```
SELECT department_id, manager_id, last_name, location_id
FROM employees NATURAL JOIN departments
WHERE department_id = 80
ORDER BY location_id desc;

DEPARTMENT_ID MANAGER_ID LAST_NAME                 LOCATION_ID
------------- ---------- ------------------------- -----------
       80        149 Abel                             2500
       80        149 Grant                            2500
       80        149 Taylor                           2500

SELECT department_id, departments.manager_id, last_name, location_id
FROM employees JOIN departments
USING (department_id)
WHERE department_id = 80
ORDER BY location_id desc;

DEPARTMENT_ID MANAGER_ID LAST_NAME                 LOCATION_ID
------------- ---------- ------------------------- -----------
       80        149 Zlotkey                         2500 <-Additional Line*
       80        149 Grant                           2500
       80        149 Taylor                          2500
       80        149 Abel                            2500
```

Any help and advice is appreciated!

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is one of the "features" of SQL which IMO should never EVER be used.

Comment: So from this example I don't necessarily think NJ was to blame. If I'm not mistaken it actually produced the correct output. Though my understanding of NJ and it's unreliability is small. If you don't mind, could you explain to me or direct me to a resource that demonstrate's in layman's terms how NJ is unreliable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because NATURAL JOIN joins on all columns with equal names, hence your NJ query will join on manager_id as well, whereas the USING form will not

If you examine the USING form you’ll see that the manager_id in each table is different. (Make your query `SELECT *` and you’ll see..)

When natural joined this difference in manager_id between the two tables will remove the row from the results

It’s probably worth noting that natural join and using should be seldom used. For sure learn about them so you can appreciate their existence, but you should stick to using regular explicit joins for reasons of consistent and clear behaviour - if the app is upgraded in future and two new columns are added to these two tables, named the same but will different data the NJ will fail.

Edit:

Run this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees JOIN departments
USING (department_id)
WHERE department_id = 80
ORDER BY location_id desc;
```

Look at the two columns showing manager ID. The data on the Zlotkey row will be different

You natural join effectively did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees e JOIN departments d
on e.department_id = d.department_id AND e.manager_id = d.manager_id
WHERE department_id = 80
ORDER BY location_id desc;
```

And `on e.department_id = d.department_id AND e.manager_id = d.manager_id` is not true for the zlotkey row

This is why natural join is risky and possibly useless - just because two columns have the same name doesn’t mean the data in them is related. Indeed in your case your departments have managers and your employees have managers. I also have this setup at my work, but the man who is my manager is not the manager of the department I work in

Comment: Thanks for your response! So when you say that there's a difference between manager_id in both tables, what do you mean specifically? When I check manager_id in both tables, all I see is that there are more rows in table employees compared to table departments, but they have the same value.

table departments - 7 rows selected.
table employees - 51 rows selected.

Comment: Ok after looking at the row, the manager_id = 100 in table employees and manager_id = 149 in table departments. So because of this difference, NJ leaves this row out? If so, I think I know what happened with USING. So in the USING clause, the column specified was department_id. This caused the row to be produced despite having a different manager_id.

Comment: Yes, if you see the edit to my answer I point this out toward the end. If you were to write USING(department_id, manager_id) the row would disappear again. Moral of the story: don’t use natural join, because it’s nearly always a bad idea. Saving a few key presses now isn’t worth the pain it’ll cause later. Don’t use USING because it’s not standard SQL

Comment: Hi I have another question. So to avoid a situation like I had with the USING clause (where I had Zlotkey incorrectly added), I should always make sure that every matching column from each table is set equal to each other (i.e. ON e.department_id = d.department_id AND e.manager_id = d.manager_id)? Since I had only one condition for matching columns the error was produced.

Comment: `USING` is fine to use.  `NATURAL JOIN` is an abomination and should not have been included in the language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff USING would be fine, if all vendors supported it; I generally advocate avoiding use of vendor specific syntax if possible

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . `USING` is ANSI/ISO standard syntax.  It is up to vendors to support it, but I would say most do.

Comment: "two new columns are added to these two tables, named the same but will different data... just because two columns have the same name doesn’t mean the data in them is related" - sounds like bad idea to me. Just because SQL allows you to do this, doesn't make it a good idea. I go with (a) giving different things different names, and (b) using the same thing the same name everywhere. Here, `NATURAL JOIN` exposes flaws in the OP's schema, don't blame `NATURAL JOIN` for that.

Comment: I think having a table called EthernetHardware that has an Address column, and an Employee that has an Address column is pretty reasonable. I'm not about to prefix the table name onto every column name just to make sure they're distinct, and my CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, DeletedDate, Status, Type, Id etc columns don't clash with other tables. `NATURAL JOIN` is a dead duck

Comment: @GordonLinoff: "`NATURAL JOIN` is an abomination" - Hate is for haters.

Comment: Looks more like an astute observation than hate to me

Answer (score -2):

My first piece of advice is to apply the 'single responsibility' principle to your schema. Think about the role/persona who would update the data and under what circumstances they would do it. Bottom line: the `employees` table has 'too much responsibility'. Employee name and hire date normally change less frequently than salary. Salary would be accessed every pay day. Phone number might be private. Consider creating new tables by splitting up the `employees` table based on responsibilities.

Second, think about differentiating between (a) tables that model 'entities' such as employees, and (b) tables that model relationships between those entities. Your two tables currently mix these two concepts. Consider a new table for the org char relationship (who manages whom) and a further table to model the relationship between employees and departments.

Third, think about whether you are giving the same data element the same name throughout your schema e.g. may 'an employee's manger' and 'a department's manager' have different meanings (e.g. in queries involving both you find you have to rename at least one of them to avoid confusion). If so, consider making the name more explicit and don't reply on the table name to give in context.

After redesigning your schema in line with the above advice, you will likely find your queries work as expected. TL;DR if you are finding it hard to write simple SQL DML, consider modifying your SQL DDL.